# Openshift CLI: Change .kube folder to different drive

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-3

I have Openshift CLI 3.11 installed on my machine, but my .kube folder is present on my H drive(network drive) which is not accessible due to some network problems as I'm away from my office and connected remotely .
So whenever I try to login from CLI with 'oc login xxxx:port', I get below error

[image]

How can I change my .kube location to C drive .

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, you want to specify other kubeconfig file path instead of $HOME/.kube/config. Is it right ? Then this reference would be helpful for you.
Refer [Loading and Merging Rules](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/cli_reference/manage_cli_profiles.html#loading-and-merging-rules) for more details.

For instance, you can specify the kubeconfig "--config" option or KUBECONFIG environment value as follows.

```
$ oc login --config /path/to/your/config -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD

OR

$ KUBECONFIG=/path/to/your/config oc login -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the **HOME** environment variable as well as the **HOMEDRIVE**, it might be something like (example checked on git-bash):

```
$ echo $HOME
/H/
```

Change it with

```
$ HOME=/O/
```

If it still complaints, check the rest of enviroment variables (still git-bash)

```
printenv | less
```